# date filter on excel range using vba does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter between a date range in excel using vba.
It is not working.

However when I perform a manual filter, it works.
So I recorded the macro and applied the same code.
Again, it did not work.

Date format in file is as below:

[image]

Let's say I am trying to filter out 01 to 31 July 2021.

Here's my code that does not work: Date in in A column.

```
startDT = ActiveSheet.txtStartDT.Text   '01-Jul-2021
endDT = ActiveSheet.txtEndDT.Text    '31-Jul-2021

For Each srcWsht In srcWbk.Worksheets
            lastSrcRow = srcWsht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                        
            srcWsht.Range("A2:A" & lastSrcRow).Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            srcWsht.Range("A2:A" & lastSrcRow).NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            
            srcWsht.Range("A1:O" & lastSrcRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDate(startDT), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDate(endDT), visibledropdown:=True
                 
            
            srcWsht.Range("A2:O" & lastSrcRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            
            wshtData.Range("A" & lastDataRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            lastDataRow = wshtData.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1
            
Next srcWsht
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter needs a numeric value to filter. But if you concatenate a `String` with a `Date` as you do in `">=" & CDate(startDT)` it will implicitly convert your numeric date into a string to concatenate it. Depending on your default date format set in your operating system (mine is `yyyy-mm-dd`) this will result in something like `">=2021-07-01"` which is not considered as a date but as a formula to calculate and it will subtratct `07` and `01` from `2021` and your filter does `>=2013` which is not what you want.

So by converting your `Date` into a `Double` like `CDbl(CDate(startDT))` you convert the date `2021-07-01` into `44378` which is the actual numeric value of the date that is stored in your cells. Now your filter does `>=44378` and this will work

```
srcWsht.Range("A1:O" & lastSrcRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(CDate(startDT)), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate(endDT)), visibledropdown:=True
```

---

Note your values are `Strings` (text that look like dates) if the begin with `'`. If you now remove that `'` Excel will convert them to numeric dates (so that you can calculate and filter them). But Excel guesses the format. So in case they are `dd-MMM-yyyy` Excel has it pretty clear which format it is and will guess correctly but be carefull with strings like `01/05/2022` where Excel cannot know if this is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`. If you let Excel convert that it is a 50/50 chance to get it wrong or right!

If that is the case you need to split your strings that look like dates apart into day, month and year, and use `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)` to convert it into a real numeric date. This way you define which format `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` your strings are and you do not let Excel guess (and maybe come up with the wrong one).

You might also need to do that if your month names are english `01-May-2021` but you work in another localized system (like I do in German). Because the German Excel has no idea how to convert `May` into a month because in German it is `Mai`. So Excel cannot convert that automatically and you need to split and convert that with your own function too (or it will only work in English Excels).

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your solution worked and explained very clearly what's going on behind the screen.